# Babel-standalone exist in production bundle

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-polyfill

After production-mode build there is a `babel-standalone` module in my bundle. But i never installed this `babel-standalone` manually. And it doesn't exist in `package.json` either. But i installed the `babel-polyfill` in this project, does `babel-standalone` come with babel-polyfill? How can i remove this module from bundle so that can reduce the size of production bundle?

The screen shot from `webpack-bundle-analyzer` is like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`babel-polyfill` doesn't depend on `babel-standalone`. There is something else that is importing it. You can run `npm ls babel-standalone` or `yarn why babel-standalone` to see why it's installed.

After figuring out *why* `babel-standalone` is included in your bundle, if you are sure that neither you nor your dependencies need it (it's used to compile JS code on-the-fly in the browser rather than at build time), you can remove it by using Webpack's [`null-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/null-loader/):

```
  rules: [
    {
      // Adjust this path to match the path of the imported babel-standalone file
      test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/babel-standalone/babel.js'),
      use: 'null-loader',
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But after i run `npm ls babel-standalone`, the result is empty.  I edit my question for some details. Can you help me to check a bit ?

Comment: From the original answer I assume that the packages you were seeing was `babel-standalone` and not `@babel/standalone`. You can use `npm ls @babel/standalone` to see why it's included.